# Does PostgreSQL allow running stored procedures in parallel?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with an ETL tool, Business Objects Data Services, which has the capability of specifying parallel execution of functions.  The documentation says that before you can do this, you have to make sure that your database, which in our case is Postgres, allows "a stored procedure to run in parallel".  Can anyone tell me if Postgres does that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. Just run your queries in different connections, and they will run in parallel transactions. Beware of locking though.

Comment: you mean they're gonna be serialized in the same connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can also call different stored procedures from the `same connection` (and effectively still run them in parallel) by using [DBLink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/dblink.html).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376210/postgresql-how-split-a-query-between-multiple-cpu/23377434#answer-36274457) SO answer to see an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use pgcron to schedule the procedure as many times you want.  Use arguments to make the procedure act on different sets of data.